# How to return a pointer to structure in C...?

Tags: c

I am new to C programming....
Here is my sample code....

I want to write a function that should return a pointer to a structure... when I compiled the below code... I got the segmentation fault.....
I know, I am doing some small mistake...Any suggestion to this problem would be helpful for me...

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct point *test(int x, int y);

struct point {
int x;
int y;
};


int main() {

struct point* val2;

int xx, yy;

xx = 1;

yy = 2;

val2 = test(xx, yy);


 }

struct point *test (int xx, int yy) {

struct point *a;

a->x = xx;

a->y = yy;

return (a);

}
```

Makefile used

```
CC = gcc

Phony = .clean

main: main.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $<
clean:
    rm *.o
```

Output Received:

```
 Segmentation fault(Core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you think `struct point *a;` points at?

Comment: `struct point *a` is not allocated and doesn't point to valid address. Also always use a debugger like `gdb` to debug

Comment: You have to assign `a` a sensible value before you use it.

Comment: Garbage de-ref, my favorite cause of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: a) pointers can hold the adress of a second variable, but they dont always do that (but your code looks like you assume they would). b) The cases where you need a raw pointer are quite rare, just dont use them until you need to. Why do you want to return a pointer when simply returning a value will do?

Comment: Tip: If you replace `struct point { ... };` with `typedef struct { ... } point;`, you get to use `point` instead of `struct point` everywhere.

Comment: Comment removed, disdain remains.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestion.

This code replaced the issue....

```
struct point *test (int xx, int yy) {
  struct point *a = malloc(sizeof *a); 
  a->x = xx;
  a->y = yy;
return (a);
}
```

Comment: You can validate if the correct  struct has returned with this line in your main: printf( "%d %d\n", val2->x, val2->y);

Comment: More to the point, you want to malloc the size of the struct; malloc(sizeof(point))